# I want to use the jquery-ui datepicker in handsontable(version 0.22.0)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, handsontable

I have using the handsontable(version 0.22.0)

I want to use the jquery-ui datepicker at the convenience of the design.

But jquery-ui datepicker in 0.12.6 has been removed
(https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/releases/tag/0.12.6)

Tell me how to use the jquery-ui datepicker on version 0.22.0